# VSCode: Express pathing breaks Intellisense for threeJS

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am trying to set up a threeJS-project with NodeJS and Express using VSCode. I have a `app.js` file as an entry point for NodeJS which shortens the default path to the threeJS module:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.use('/build/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/three/build')));
app.use('/jsm/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/three/examples/jsm')));
```

In another folder I have a `game.js` which imports the threeJS module like that:

```
import * as THREE from '/build/three.module.js';
import {OrbitControls} from '/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import Stats from '/jsm/libs/stats.module.js';
```

Importing works well however the intellisense is turned off for this. I can't check the declaration nor the arguments of a method like `new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100);`

If I change `import * as THREE from '/build/three.module.js';` to `import * as THREE from 'node_modules/three/build/three.js';` it works perfectly fine but that's not the way.

So how do I fix this?